# Getting Error " You haven't set up branch link propoerly" when try to open link from Branch metrics?

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

I am working on deep linking.I integrate branch.io sdk in my application. I create application on branch.io also. I create a deep link for that application. When i sent that link to device and try to open it in broswer it is showing Error message "It seems like you haven't properly set up  your Branch link. Please head to setting tab in the dashboard for more guidence."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android, in order for the link to know where to redirect to, you must configure the link settings.

Here are some requirements:
1. If you check 'I have an Android app', then you must select a destination to redirect to. You can either choose the app from Play Store, or set a Custom URL if your app is not live. If you set a Custom URL, please specify the package name of your app project that you'll test with.

Here's an example of a custom URL:
[image]

2. If you don't check 'I have an Android app', then you must specify a Default URL at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Alex what about ios? my custom url is https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/44be5e7f8c14d7c8e71da2261548853b/app_versions/12?format=ipa but it s not working

Comment: Hey Dat - I heard you're all taken care of with our support team. It sounded like an issue with Hockey. Happy linking!